# Using querySelector in variable, not in the document

Tags: javascript

Would somehow use querySelector in a variable?

*listOption_Fonts* variable has this content:

```
<option value="10">Diário do Nordeste</option><option value="12">Agência Sebrae de      Notícias</option><option value="13">ANBA - Agência de Notícias Brasil - Árabe</option><option value="14">Mundo R.I</option> (and many more)
```

Would you like something like this:

```
listOption_Fonts.querySelector('[value=' + idFontTarget + ']');
```

However, returns the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

How to solve?

I realize I could use regular expression, but I wonder if there is a more practical method.
Do I have to selection this variable directly; content it is not on the page.

Comment: If by "has this content", you mean it has a string of HTML, then no, it won't work. The `querySelector` method is for searching the DOM, not for parsing a string of text.

Comment: Why do you have to work on a string in the first place? What's the actual situation and ultimate goal?

Comment: Will simplify the question, why not not have detailed. The reason for doing this is so that X elements will be created with the contents of this variable, however, the names can be changed before that. Is more practical to change the names of some items before creating the element than later.

Comment: If you're saying that the HTML is going to be added to the DOM, but you need to make some modifications, then you're taking the wrong approach. There's no need to create them, modify them, and then insert them. Just insert them and make the desired modifications once they're in the DOM. Don't know why you think it's more practical to do it before.

Comment: I noticed that I will have this problem now, then I tested the proposal of adeneo. 
Well, I still believe that it is best to do this my way, because otherwise that would store a list of changes that must be made ​​(change text, delete). 
I'll keep testing. If not, I will do according to your suggestion.

Comment: How would that store a list of changes? Not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: The changes made (rename, delete) ​​to the items since the variable was created. Not sure how those changes would store, would have to analyze. In any case, the logic will change to another. I really messed the code. Thank you.

Comment: If you're creating elements from a string, and add it to the DOM, changes to the DOM don't affect the original string. The DOM isn't a string,  but rather is a tree structure of objects. The HTML gets parsed and turned into the tree structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ooooh, this is where the DOMParser comes in handy, I knew it would eventually

```
var listOption_Fonts = '<option value="10">Diário do Nordeste</option><option value="12">Agência Sebrae de      Notícias</option><option value="13">ANBA - Agência de Notícias Brasil - Árabe</option><option value="14">Mundo R.I</option> (and many more)';

var parser       = new DOMParser,
    doc          = parser.parseFromString(listOption_Fonts, "text/html"),
    idFontTarget = '13',
    element      = doc.querySelector('[value="' + idFontTarget + '"]');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/fAc5P/1/)

Comment: Fantastic solution! Did not know the "new DOMParser".
Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a hack, but you can do the following

```
var holder = document.createElement('div');
holder.innerHTML = ['<select>','<option value="10">Diário do Nordeste</option><option value="12">Agência Sebrae de      Notícias</option><option value="13">ANBA - Agência de Notícias Brasil - Árabe</option>','</select>'].join('');
holder.querySelector('[value="10"]').text;
>> "Diário do Nordeste"
```

The question is still, why you would need this.
I cannot imagine any situation where this would be required and couldn't be solved in a better way.

Comment: I think some versions of IE have trouble creating OPTION elements alone using `.innerHTML`. But if you add the `<select></select>` tags, I think that fixes it.

Comment: Good point, updated the example to something that would hopefully work. Or do you think it would have to set `innerHTML` to something that is wrapped in `select` and doesn't care about the parent element at all?

Comment: I think the string actually has to have the `select` tags. Even with the proper parent node as your update shows, I'm pretty sure it fails in older IE. Here's a reference: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/276228

Comment: I updated the example again so that it should in theory work.

Answer (score 0):

Just query your "option" from it parent:

```
var select = document.querySelector('select'),
    idFontTarget = 12


console.log(select.querySelector('option[value="' + idFontTarget + '"]'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XR8SA/

Comment: As the question  states, his data is in a variable and not in the document.

Comment: OH, yeah, saw that now. Then adeneo has the right way to go on this.

Comment: adeneo's solution won't work in some older browsers. May or may not be an issue for the OP.